# Why might I lose power when I open the gas too quickly?

Tags: honda, carburetor, scooter

My 1990 Honda Super Cub has a problem that seems to occur mostly after it gets wet. Sitting in neutral, if I slowly open the gas it will reach full revs easily, but if I twist straight to full throttle it will lose power and even stall.

It's an intermittent issue anyway, so it's hard to say, but I think it tends to go away when the engine warms up.

[This answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/26810/44470) suggests that this is a fairly well-known carburettor problem. What is that problem? The carb looks like the newest part of the bike, and a mechanic recently claimed to have cleaned it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If the carb has been cleaned recently, then it seems it wasn't tuned correctly upon re-installation. I'd take it back to your mechanic and ask them to finish the job. This to me is a problem with the accelerator circuit in the carb. If it's not squirting out enough fuel during enrichment, it will do exactly what you are describing.

Comment: OK. Looks like I need to read up on carb tuning! My mechanic doesn't seem to want to fix anything that ain't _completely_ broke (and doesn't speak English) so I think this one's up to me. Thanks!

Edit: I asked him to change the oil the other day and he took a sample and shook his head to say "your oil does not need changing" :D